# maven deploy - only upload ear file to nexus

Tags: maven, nexus

I have a maven project with a couple of modules. 
When I use the maven deploy plugin, all the modules are uploaded to my local Nexus server.

I want the deploy to only upload the ear file.

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-deploy-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>2.7</version>
</plugin>
```

Comment: Why do you only want to do that?  Is it for space?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use this goal: http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-deploy-plugin/deploy-file-mojo.html

> deploy:deploy-file is used to install a single artifact along with its pom. In that case the artifact information can be taken from an optionally specified pomFile, but can be completed/overriden using the command line.

You can find an example of it being used on [the usage page](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-deploy-plugin/usage.html).

Comment: You can just do the normal deploy in the respective module rather than using the deploy-file goal.

Comment: It makes it wrong because executing the goal on its own does not guarantee that the war is actually fully built and requires you to do two steps (build and then deploy), while running it with just mvn deploy in the respective modules does it all in one execution. So its not wrong per se.. but a lot more complicated than necessary.